# How to upload 2 different lists of media to Firebase Storage one by one?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am working on Chat App. It also allows the user to send media.

Issue:- Suppose a user is sending 2 different lists of media(include images, videos). When the user sends the first list of media, the upload process is started and immediately sending the second list. Both the lists are uploaded successfully on Firebase Storage. Till this ok. Now I am creating an entry in Firestore, one list as one message(document in Firestore). But the main issue is that while uploading to Firebase Storage both lists are merged, because of that, it is not creating an entry in Firestore.

How to manage the uploading of 2 different lists one by one?

The below function is inside the for loop of one list.

```
private void uploadToStorage(Uri mImageUri, int i, @NotNull List<String> downloadPath, String description) {
    String cUuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    Log.d(TAG, "downloadPathSize" + mImageUri);

    if (docId != null && !docId.isEmpty()) {
        String metaType = filesAction.GetMimeType(mImageUri);
        if (metaType.contains("image/")) {
            chatMediaUploadFolder = storageReference.child(docId).child("photos");
        } else if (metaType.contains("video")) {
            chatMediaUploadFolder = storageReference.child(docId).child("videos");
        } else if (metaType.contains("application")) {
            chatMediaUploadFolder = storageReference.child(docId).child("documents");
        }

        String finalDocId = docId;
        chatMediaUploadFolder.child(cUuid).putFile(mImageUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
                    uploadedMediaCount++;

                    String type = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getContentType();

                    if (type.contains("image"))
                        downloadPath.set(i, "chats/" + finalDocId + "/photos/" + cUuid);
                    else if (type.contains("video"))
                        downloadPath.set(i, "chats/" + finalDocId + "/videos/" + cUuid);
                    else if (type.contains("application"))
                        downloadPath.set(i, "chats/" + finalDocId + "/documents/" + cUuid);

                    Log.d(TAG, "countOfVisiteduploadToStorage: " + uploadedMediaCount);
                    Log.d(TAG, "uploadToStorage: " + downloadPath);
                    if (uploadedMediaCount == downloadPath.size()) {
                        uploadMessage(downloadPath, description);
                        asyncActivity.Successful();
                        uploadedMediaCount = 0;
                    } else if (downloadPath.size() > 1) {
                        asyncActivity.CountUploaded(uploadedMediaCount);
                    }

                })
                .addOnProgressListener(taskSnapshot -> {
                    
                    System.out.println("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
                    asyncActivity.Progress(0, progress);
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error========" + e.getMessage());
                    
                    asyncActivity.UploadFailed(e.getMessage());
                })
                .addOnPausedListener(taskSnapshot -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error========" + taskSnapshot.getError().getMessage());
                    asyncActivity.UploadFailed(taskSnapshot.getError().getMessage());
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: Both lists are uploaded simultaneously because of that not getting uploadItemCount correctly and because of that next uploadMessage() the method is not called for the first list. And downloadPath list size is equal to the size of the first list of media.

Comment: @ShyamalyLakhadive The code the you shared is uploading a single file. Can you show the code where the function is called and where are the `lists` that you mentioned in the comment above?

As a possible solution, you could hold the value of the last entry in both lists and when the whole upload has ended, you check your storage for those two files, confirm that they are there, and then trigger your Firestore call.